# mod_rewrite RewriteCond match root directory + file name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble converting the following links

```
http://example.com/test
```

to

```
http://example.com/pages.php?p=test
```

but then not convert the following links

```
http://example.com/foo/test (http://example.com/foo/pages.php?p=test)
http://example.com/bar/test (http://example.com/bar/pages.php?p=test)
```

My current setup is this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$1$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ pages.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

I am seeming to have trouble with the last `RewriteCond (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$1$)` not seeming to detect the URL change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert **/test** to **/pages.php?p=test** you can use the following rule:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /pages.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Awesome that works, Can you explain to me why that works, to me it looks the same as including all urls. Is there something I am missing?